# I have a question about homotopy of the unit circumference with a point

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> **Definition:** Let $\gamma_0,\gamma_1:[0,1]\to G$ two rectifiable curves and $G\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ an open connected set. We say $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are homotopic in $G$ if there exists $\Gamma:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to G$ continuous such that:
>
> \begin{cases} 
>       \Gamma(s,0)=\gamma_0(s), \Gamma(s,1)=\gamma_1(s) & 0\le s\le 1 \\
>       \Gamma(0,t)=\Gamma(1,t) & 0\le t\le 1 \\
>    \end{cases}

The question is:

> Show that if we remove the condition "$\Gamma(0,t)=\Gamma(1,t)$" in the above definition, then the curves $\gamma_0(s)=e^{2\pi i s}$ and $\gamma_1(s)=1$ if $0\le s\le 1$ would be homotopic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

I defined by $\Gamma(s,t) = t + (1-t)e^{2\pi is}$.

This function satisfies the definition, but I saw in a topology article that the unit circumference is not homotopic with point 1. So where is my error?

Comment: Notice that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}e^{\pi i} = 0$, so your homotopy doesn't stay inside $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0\}$

Comment: Good! Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Gamma$ doesn't stay inside $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.  So no homotopy, and no contradiction.

For the question itself, how about $\Gamma(s,t)=e^{2\pi i s(1-t)}$.

Comment: but, the function that i defined satisfies the second condition. In this case, are they homotopic?

Comment: the function you defined is a homotopy in $\mathbb{C}$, but not in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ like the problem requires

Comment: I understand, thanks!